# Select local xml file into table

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xslt

I have a column in my table that is set as xslt (XML(.), not null).

Right now I have used a regular string to set it. Like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET xslt = 
'<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="data">
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#a0acbc">
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="row">
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'
WHERE ....
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET xslt = C:\test\Test.xlm
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
   select 
      cast(x as xml)
   from 
      OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\test\Test.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) myXml(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to read things off the drives of the server the database engine is on, it isn't easily possible for SQL Server to read things from the disks of other machines on the network.  And in many environments, developers aren't allowed to access the drives of the server running SQL Server.

There are a couple of ways to get what you want, though:

1. Use an SSIS package to load your stylesheet and update your table.
2. Write a short program (or ask to have someone write one) that reads in your file and uses the contents as a parameter value in a SQL update statement.
3. Do you have a way to execute a stylesheet against an arbitrary text file?  Then write a stylesheet to wrap the contents of your XSLT file with a SQL update statement, thus generating you a script to use to update your table.